# how to convert time to eppoch time based on date?

Tags: unix-timestamp

I need a javascript function which should take two arguments they are  date and time (i.e 9 ,10 ,18,19 etc) and it should return eppoch time for that exact date and time?
please help me?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
var myDate = new Date("July 1, 1978 02:30:00"); 
var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000.0;
document.write(myEpoch);
```